# Unable to cast object of type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject even though I am trying to cast to an object with matching properties

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core-2.0, json-deserialization, c#-7.0, httpresponsemessage

I am working with ASP.NET Core 2.0 in VS2017.

I am trying to deserialize some JSON that is returned in an `HttpResponseMessage` but I am getting an "Unable to cast object of type..." exception.

Here is the code that is failing;

```
FilesUploadedListResponse fileUploadListResponse = new FilesUploadedListResponse();
string jsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
fileUploadListResponse = (FilesUploadedListResponse)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResult);
```

The last line is where I get the exception...

```
"Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'FilesUploadedListResponse'."
```

Here is the actual Json that is in the string `jsonResult`:

```
"{\"uploadedfiles\":[],\"totalResults\":0,\"pageNumber\":0,\"pageSize\":0}"
```

The `uploadedFiles` array is empty in this result, because there are no uploaded files yet, but I would think that having it empty shouldn't create an exception, should it? If it were not empty, it would have a response similar to this:

```
{
 "uploadedFiles": [
 {
 "id": 1,
 "createdTime": "July 10, 2017 02:02:25 PM",
 "filename": "20170710_14022507701.jpg",
 "sentTime": "July 10, 2017 02:05:11 PM",
 "fileSize": "124 KB"
 },
 {
 "id": 2,
 "createdTime": "June 05, 2017 09:39:25 AM",
 "filename": "20170605_093907701.jpg",
 "sentTime": "June 05, 2017 09:40:11 AM",
 "fileSize": "1 MB"
 }
],
 "totalResults": 2,
 "pageNumber": 0,
 "pageSize": 2
}
```

Here is my `FileUploadListResponse` class:

```
public class FilesUploadedListResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public List<UploadedFile> UploadedFiles { get; set; }
    public int TotalResults { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my `UploadedFile` class:

```
public class UploadedFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SentTime { get; set; }
    public string FileSize { get; set; }
}
```

My understanding of the JSON deserialization is that:

1. The case of the elements doesn't matter between the values in the JSON string and the class object I am trying to deserialize to.
2. The class I am trying to deserialize to can have more properties that what is provided in the JSON string, just as long as the properties that are in the JSON string are accounted for.
3. An empty sub array, such as the `UploadedFiles` array should not cause an error when trying to deserialize to the `List<UploadedFile>`

I am sure it is something simple, but I am just not seeing it. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why aren't you just doing `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FilesUploadedListResponse>(jsonResult)`?

Comment: I have found that you can have  "jsonkey": "12"  in the JSON even if  jsonKey is not defined in the target type.  Still seems to work ok.

Comment: an empty sub array with your posted json would fail as you are missing several required properties on FilesUploadedListResponse: Success, StatusCode, and Reason are all missing and are all required fields if they are optional you should add a ? to them

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call the non-generic method [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResult)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm), you are asking Json.NET to deserialize the incoming JSON into some .Net type *of its own choosing* that is sufficient to capture the incoming JSON.   What it in fact chooses is a [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).  Since this type is not implicitly or explicitly [convertible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/using-conversion-operators) to your `FilesUploadedListResponse` type, you get the exception you see.

Since want to deserialize to a specific, known type, you should instead call the generic method [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FilesUploadedListResponse>(jso‌​nResult)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm) which *Deserializes the JSON to the specified .NET type* like so:

```
string jsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var fileUploadListResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FilesUploadedListResponse>(jsonResult);
```

Comment: Thanks dbc. That did the trick. Everything is working correctly now.

Comment: To whom may need it, in VB.net is JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of FilesUploadedListResponse)(jsonResult)