# How to cast object of type Object to List<AnotherObject>

Tags: c#, json

I will try to explain my issue. I want to deserialize JSON to c# classes in my application. One of my classes has a property of type object:

```
public object invoiceDetails { get; set; }
```

I have made it of type object because it was the only type that the JSON deserialized successfully. The actual property in the JSON object is either type array([]) or type object({}). When it is of type object, it consists of a few other objects and can be deserialized successfully with List<> or Dictionary<>. The problem is that I need to use that object property as a List and tried to cast it to a List like this:

```
(List<InvoiceDetails)entry.Value.invoiceDetails
```

But without success. I've also tried to cast it to an array and dictionary, but again unsuccessfully. Then I started digging in the internet for a solution and I've found some code, finally my code is:

```
if ((entry.Value.invoiceDetails != null) && ((IList)entry.Value.invoiceDetails).Count > 0)
{
  IList objList = (IList)entry.Value.invoiceDetails;
  IEnumerable<InvoiceDetails> list = objList.Cast<InvoiceDetails>();
  //List<InvoiceDetails> listToIterate = list.ToList();
  foreach (var item in list)
  {
    if (item.invoice_ref != null)
    {
      UpdateEntry("tbl_ts_InvoiceDetails", "invoice_ref", item.invoice_ref, item.id);
    }

    if (item.bill_note != null)
    {
      UpdateEntry("tbl_ts_InvoiceDetails", "bill_note", item.bill_note, item.id);
    }
  }
}
```

I have, successfully, cast "invoiceDetails" to IList but when I enter the foreach, it throws me the error:

> "Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' to type 'TicketSystemDataTransferService.Models.InvoiceDetails'."

When I tried to execute the commented code (... = list.ToList()) I receive the same error message.

Can you give me an advice how can I cast invoiceDetails to a c# List<> so I can use it?

Comment: Can you show us the deserialization code?

Comment: RootObject deserializedJSONChanged = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content2, new JsonChangeConverter());

Comment: Sorry, I think you are asking for this: {[
  {
    "id": 26,
    "invoice_ref": "AJ Beijing [CN] 0113",
    "bill_note": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "invoice_ref": "AJ Blomesystem GmbH [DE] 0103",
    "bill_note": ""
  }
]}

Comment: Similar question: [Unable to cast object of type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject even though I am trying to cast to an object with matching properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48130753/3744182).  This should have a similar answer, which is to use typed rather than untyped deserialization.

Comment: *The actual property in the JSON object is either type array([]) or type object({}).* - them maybe this is an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you are really looking for [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182).  Also, please [edit] your question to share examples of the JSON you are trying to deserialize.  As it is your question lacks a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is how to use Newtonsoft:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Item item = new Item { Name = "Test Item" }; //Create an Item entity
        string jsonItem = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item); //Convert given Item to json
        Item lastItem = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(jsonItem); //Convert given json in Item

        List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item { Name ="Test Item 1" },
            new Item { Name ="Test Item 2" },
            new Item { Name ="Test Item 3" },
            new Item { Name ="Test Item 4" },
            new Item { Name ="Test Item 5" }
        }; //Create a list of Item
        string jsonListItems = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items); //Convert given list of Item to json
        List<Item> lastListItems = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(jsonListItems); //Convert given json in list of Item
    }

}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your example. I deserialized my json successfully. I just want to find how to cast from Object to List<>.

Comment: So you didn't deserialize your json succesfully.

Comment: No I deserialized it successfully. I have no problem with the json.

Comment: Okay so I can't help you if you don't need help, right? ^^

Comment: My problem is that one property of the one of the c# classes is of type object but I need it to be of type List I don't know how to cast from Object to List<InvoiceDetails> in c#

Comment: It isn't castable, the "object" that you get is not what you want.