# How to deserialize JSON to XPO objects using the current session?

Tags: c#, json.net, xaf, xpo

I have serialized xpo objects into JSON data in separate project using default session. But when I try to de-serialize the same within view controller i am getting default session error. I am able to get the current session but I am not sure how to deserialize by using the current session.

Newtonsoft is being used to serialize and deserialize.

```
string filetext= File.ReadAllText("importedfile.json");
Plugin pl = (Plugin)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(filetext,jsonsettings);
```

Plugin is my class name to which the JSON data should get deserialized.

Comment: First of all you need to do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Plugin>(filetext,jsonsettings)` to deserialize to a `Plugin`.  See [Unable to cast object of type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject even though I am trying to cast to an object with matching properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48130933/3744182) for why.  Does that solve your problem, or do you have some additional issue?  If so might you [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?

Comment: Actually, `Plugin` is my XPO object that cannot be instantiated without the session. But I am not sure how to provide the session when deserializing.

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] to answer your question, but maybe a [`CustomCreationConverter<Plugin>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomCreationConverter.htm) that creates the `Plugin` from some factory method would work.

Comment: Is this how your `Plugin` is created: https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/2077/create-a-data-model/create-a-persistent-object#declare-a-persistent-object

Answer (score 1):

Presuming your `Plugin` type inherits from [`DevExpress.Xpo.XPObject`](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/DevExpress.Xpo.XPObject) in the manner shown in the [documentation example](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/DevExpress.Xpo.XPObject#remarks):

```
public class Plugin : XPObject {
    // XPObject has a built-in Integer key and you can't add a custom key
    public Plugin(Session session) : base(session) { }
    string fMyProperty;
    public string MyProperty {
        get { return fMyProperty; }
        set { SetPropertyValue(nameof(fMyProperty), ref fMyProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And assuming that your deserialization code already has access to some [`Session session`](https://docs.devexpress.com/XPO/DevExpress.Xpo.Session), then define the following [`CustomCreationConverter<Plugin>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomCreationConverter.htm):

```
public class PluginConverter : CustomCreationConverter<Plugin>
{
    DevExpress.Xpo.Session Session { get; }

    public PluginConverter(DevExpress.Xpo.Session session) => this.Session = session ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();

    public override Plugin Create(Type objectType) => new Plugin(Session);
}
```

And deserialize as follows:

```
Session session; // Your session

var jsonsettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new PluginConverter(session), /* Other converters as required */ },
    // Other settings as required
};
var pl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Plugin>(filetext, jsonsettings);
```

When deserializing the type `Plugin` the converter's `Create()` method will be invoked to manufacture the `Plugin` using the provided session.

If you are using multiple sessions, you will need to use a new `JsonSerializerSettings` for each new session.

This pattern can be used for any type inheriting from `XPObject` with a public constructor taking a `Session` object.